# mysql - return results grouped in a column

Tags: php, mysql, search, search-engine

I am working on a search/tag system. My original query I wrote was for when I was storing 'title', 'description' and a comma seperated 'tags' column in my article/video table. I have since realised the advantage of normalising my tags. I now have three table to deal with...

**tbl_Articles**

- article_id
- title
- description
- content

**tbl_tag_index**

- tag_id (surrogate primary id)
- tag_type (equals 1 for tbl_Articles,
  2 for tbl_videos)
- tag_word_id (see table bellow)
- tag_target_id (article_id/video_id -
  depends on tag_type)

**tbl_tag_word**

- tag_word_id
- tag_word (finally the actual tag)

This query returns the tags... only problem is it returns them as different rows. I guess I would need the results to be grouped to the same row so that my search query may work

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `tbl_articles` A 
  JOIN `tag_index` I ON A.article_id = I.tag_target_id 
  JOIN tag_word W ON I.tag_word_id = W.tag_word_id 
 WHERE I.tag_type_id = 1
```

Here is my old search query

```
SELECT *, 
(
(CASE WHEN `description` LIKE '%hotel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN `description` LIKE '%london%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN `description` LIKE '%lazy%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN `description` LIKE '%dog%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +

(CASE WHEN `title` LIKE '%hotel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN `title` LIKE '%london%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN `title` LIKE '%lazy%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN `title` LIKE '%dog%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +

(CASE WHEN `tags` LIKE '%hotel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN `tags` LIKE '%london%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN `tags` LIKE '%lazy%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
(CASE WHEN `tags` LIKE '%dog%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

) AS relevance
FROM `tbl_Articles`
WHERE `description` LIKE '%hotel%'
  OR `description` LIKE '%london%'
  OR `description` LIKE '%lazy%'
  OR `description` LIKE '%dog%' 
  OR `title` LIKE '%hotel%'
  OR `title` LIKE '%london%'
  OR `title` LIKE '%lazy%'
  OR `title` LIKE '%dog%'
  OR `tags` LIKE '%hotel%'
  OR `tags` LIKE '%london%'
  OR `tags` LIKE '%lazy%'
  OR `tags` LIKE '%dog%'
ORDER BY relevance DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

Comment: Updated based on comment about tag relevance calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT A.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.tag_word ORDER BY w.tag_word ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS tags,
       COUNT(DISTINCT w.tag_word) +
       (CASE WHEN `description` LIKE '%hotel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       (CASE WHEN `description` LIKE '%london%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       (CASE WHEN `description` LIKE '%lazy%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       (CASE WHEN `description` LIKE '%dog%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +

       (CASE WHEN `title` LIKE '%hotel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       (CASE WHEN `title` LIKE '%london%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       (CASE WHEN `title` LIKE '%lazy%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       (CASE WHEN `title` LIKE '%dog%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS relevance
  FROM tbl_articles A 
  JOIN tag_index I ON A.article_id = I.tag_target_id 
  JOIN tag_word W ON I.tag_word_id = W.tag_word_id 
 WHERE I.tag_type_id = 1
   AND w.tag_word IN ('hotel', 'london', 'lazy', 'dog')
GROUP BY a.article_id, a.title, a.description, a.content
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Comment: wow, that is fantastic!
How might I integrate the like title and description?

Comment: sorry, maybe I was not clear in my post, I still wish to search the same, only instead of the tags being a column they are in a separate table. Thank you.

Comment: Your solution was more efficient than mine. Still I do not see how 'COUNT(DISTINCT w.tag_word)' will search the tags for their likeness to the search term :S